# Running as Eclipse Application causes JVM Crash - “EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION”

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, crash, java-8

I am developing an eclipse plugin and use an eclipse application run/debug configuration to run it for testing purposes. Since I changed to JDK1.8 the nested eclipse application crashes. This happens if try to navigate to a class from a dependent project using ctrl+click or if use auto-completion on a class from a library. I am on Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2) using the latest JDK8 update (45) and the latest stable M2E 1.5.2.20150413-2215. Here's a part of crash log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006e99619f, pid=2212, tid=3596
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b15) (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x4b619f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000056652000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3596, stack(0x00000000587b0000,0x00000000588b0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000008

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x00000000631f6e00, RDX=0x0000000000004000
RSP=0x00000000588abc30, RBP=0x00000000645eb948, RSI=0x00000000631f6e00, RDI=0x00000000588ac100
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000063828f30, R10=0x00000000588ac100, R11=0x0000000058e35260
R12=0x000000005ba69af8, R13=0x000000005a99f238, R14=0x00000000588abd18, R15=0x00000000588abd38
RIP=0x000000006e99619f, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010287

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000588abc30)
0x00000000588abc30:   00000000645ec080 00000000645eb948
0x00000000588abc40:   00000000631f6e00 00000000588ac100
0x00000000588abc50:   00000000645eb948 00000000588abd88
0x00000000588abc60:   0000000000000017 000000006e9979a9
0x00000000588abc70:   00000000645ec080 00000000000005a9
0x00000000588abc80:   0000000000000001 00000000631f6e00
0x00000000588abc90:   00000000588acad0 000000006e9ca280
0x00000000588abca0:   000000005c7b80a0 00000000566372d0
0x00000000588abcb0:   00000000736c5e80 00000000588abde0
0x00000000588abcc0:   00000000566372d0 0000000000000000
0x00000000588abcd0:   00000000588ac100 000000006e99988f
0x00000000588abce0:   00000000588ac100 0000000000000001
0x00000000588abcf0:   0000000000000001 00000000736c5e80
0x00000000588abd00:   000000005c7b80f0 000000005c7c0088
0x00000000588abd10:   00000000000ede60 00000000566372d0
0x00000000588abd20:   0000000000000800 0000000058e1e290 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006e99619f)
0x000000006e99617f:   4c 89 64 24 50 4c 8b e0 4c 3b e8 0f 84 4f 01 00
0x000000006e99618f:   00 44 8b 43 28 4c 8b 8f f0 09 00 00 4b 8b 1c c1
0x000000006e99619f:   48 8b 43 08 48 83 38 00 75 2a 8b 57 28 0f 1f 40
0x000000006e9961af:   00 8b 43 28 3b c2 73 0c 8b c8 48 8b 47 30 48 8b 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000000631f6e00 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000004000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00000000588abc30 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000056652000
RBP=0x00000000645eb948 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00000000631f6e00 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000588ac100 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000056652000
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000063828f30 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000588ac100 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000056652000
R11=0x0000000058e35260 is an unknown value
R12=0x000000005ba69af8 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000005a99f238 is an unknown value
R14=0x00000000588abd18 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000056652000
R15=0x00000000588abd38 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000056652000


Stack: [0x00000000587b0000,0x00000000588b0000],  sp=0x00000000588abc30,  free space=1007k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x4b619f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4b79a9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4b988f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x46bf81]
V  [jvm.dll+0x46ccbe]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4500f2]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa4352]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa4c8f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x241984]
V  [jvm.dll+0x29853a]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21d9f]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21e3b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x159cd]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2b981]


Current CompileTask:
C2:2793722 37962       4       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.TypeConverter::decodeType (1094 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000065a91800 JavaThread "Additional info timer" [_thread_blocked, id=5496, stack(0x0000000078f40000,0x0000000079040000)]
  0x000000005e163800 JavaThread "Recommenders-Bus-Thread-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5888, stack(0x000000007c5a0000,0x000000007c6a0000)]
  0x0000000059eff800 JavaThread "Recommenders-Timeout-Manager" [_thread_blocked, id=5872, stack(0x000000007b2a0000,0x000000007b3a0000)]
  0x0000000070332800 JavaThread "Recommenders-Bus-Thread-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1376, stack(0x000000007ad20000,0x000000007ae20000)]
  0x0000000064830800 JavaThread "Recommenders-Bus-Thread-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1476, stack(0x0000000076ff0000,0x00000000770f0000)]
  0x000000006482f000 JavaThread "Recommenders-Bus-Thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6036, stack(0x000000007c060000,0x000000007c160000)]
  0x000000005db80800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6492, stack(0x000000007b610000,0x000000007b710000)]
  0x000000005db7f000 JavaThread "Recommenders-Bus-Thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=780, stack(0x0000000079060000,0x0000000079160000)]
  0x0000000066276000 JavaThread "Recommenders-Bus-Thread-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6600, stack(0x000000007b490000,0x000000007b590000)]
  0x000000005a33f000 JavaThread "com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5944, stack(0x000000007bbc0000,0x000000007bcc0000)]
  0x000000005a33f800 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6340, stack(0x0000000079180000,0x0000000079280000)]
  0x000000005e162000 JavaThread "Worker-21" [_thread_blocked, id=4132, stack(0x000000006c450000,0x000000006c550000)]
  0x0000000064836000 JavaThread "Worker-18" [_thread_blocked, id=6324, stack(0x0000000063f80000,0x0000000064080000)]
  0x000000005c57f800 JavaThread "Worker-17" [_thread_blocked, id=2896, stack(0x000000006d610000,0x000000006d710000)]
  0x000000005c57e800 JavaThread "Worker-16" [_thread_blocked, id=6840, stack(0x00000000741d0000,0x00000000742d0000)]
  0x0000000070333000 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6644, stack(0x0000000064350000,0x0000000064450000)]
  0x000000005a342000 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=6632, stack(0x000000006c620000,0x000000006c720000)]
  0x000000005e164800 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6468, stack(0x000000006bac0000,0x000000006bbc0000)]
  0x000000005e161800 JavaThread "JavaScript indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6420, stack(0x0000000069150000,0x0000000069250000)]
  0x000000005e160000 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6412, stack(0x0000000069bf0000,0x0000000069cf0000)]
  0x000000005db85000 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=6332, stack(0x0000000061490000,0x0000000061590000)]
  0x000000005c57b800 JavaThread "EventAdmin Async Event Dispatcher Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5368, stack(0x0000000061110000,0x0000000061210000)]
  0x000000005db84000 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2136, stack(0x0000000060de0000,0x0000000060ee0000)]
  0x000000005db7e000 JavaThread "EMF Reference Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=196, stack(0x000000005ecc0000,0x000000005edc0000)]
  0x000000005cf35800 JavaThread "Gogo shell" [_thread_in_native, id=1468, stack(0x000000005d9a0000,0x000000005daa0000)]
  0x000000005ba3e800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=2024, stack(0x000000005b3c0000,0x000000005b4c0000)]
  0x0000000059b15800 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2892, stack(0x000000005b4e0000,0x000000005b5e0000)]
  0x000000005a13a800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3040, stack(0x000000005b2a0000,0x000000005b3a0000)]
  0x000000005a0c2800 JavaThread "Start Level: Equinox Container: 20403217-0605-0015-1aa3-ed6e033444da" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3076, stack(0x000000005af70000,0x000000005b070000)]
  0x000000005a0c2000 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 20403217-0605-0015-1aa3-ed6e033444da" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1192, stack(0x0000000059600000,0x0000000059700000)]
  0x000000005931e800 JavaThread "Active Thread: Equinox Container: 20403217-0605-0015-1aa3-ed6e033444da" [_thread_blocked, id=3320, stack(0x000000005abb0000,0x000000005acb0000)]
  0x00000000566ce000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3308, stack(0x0000000058cd0000,0x0000000058dd0000)]
  0x000000005665a800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2232, stack(0x0000000058b90000,0x0000000058c90000)]
  0x0000000056659000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4292, stack(0x0000000058960000,0x0000000058a60000)]
=>0x0000000056652000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3596, stack(0x00000000587b0000,0x00000000588b0000)]
  0x000000005664a800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4848, stack(0x0000000058080000,0x0000000058180000)]
  0x000000005663e000 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5112, stack(0x0000000058260000,0x0000000058360000)]
  0x0000000056636000 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1304, stack(0x0000000058560000,0x0000000058660000)]
  0x000000005662a800 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1800, stack(0x00000000583f0000,0x00000000584f0000)]
  0x0000000056621800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1172, stack(0x0000000057d50000,0x0000000057e50000)]
  0x0000000056620000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5056, stack(0x0000000057920000,0x0000000057a20000)]
  0x0000000055681800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1196, stack(0x0000000057ac0000,0x0000000057bc0000)]
  0x000000005567a800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3764, stack(0x0000000057800000,0x0000000057900000)]
  0x000000000228f000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4064, stack(0x0000000002450000,0x0000000002550000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000055674000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000057640000,0x0000000057740000] [id=4652]
  0x00000000566ec000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000058660000,0x0000000058760000] [id=3636]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 300544K, used 105489K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 256000K, 41% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1204588,0x00000000fa500000)
  from space 44544K, 0% used [0x00000000fd480000,0x00000000fd480000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 46592K, 0% used [0x00000000fa500000,0x00000000fa500000,0x00000000fd280000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 228000K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 51% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cdea8078,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 147194K, capacity 158576K, committed 159060K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16716K, capacity 20430K, committed 20608K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011be0000,0x0000000011df0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000115e0000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006ece4040
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012a90000, 0x0000000013a90000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000013a90000, 0x0000000014a90000)

Polling page: 0x0000000001c50000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=113536Kb max_used=114004Kb free=132223Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002820000, 0x00000000098b0000, 0x0000000011820000]
 total_blobs=25761 nmethods=24728 adapters=943
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 2792.622 Thread 0x0000000056659000 nmethod 37952 0x0000000009867390 code [0x0000000009867f00, 0x0000000009884b08]
Event: 2792.909 Thread 0x000000005664a800 37961       4       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.MemberElementInfo::<init> (5 bytes)
Event: 2792.909 Thread 0x000000005664a800 nmethod 37961 0x0000000003d0e3d0 code [0x0000000003d0e500, 0x0000000003d0e558]
Event: 2792.912 Thread 0x0000000056652000 37962       4       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.TypeConverter::decodeType (1094 bytes)
Event: 2792.917 Thread 0x000000005665a800 37963       3       org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTRecoveryPropagator::flagNodeWithInsertedTokens (95 bytes)
Event: 2792.918 Thread 0x000000005665a800 nmethod 37963 0x0000000006c2de10 code [0x0000000006c2e080, 0x0000000006c2f328]
Event: 2792.918 Thread 0x000000005665a800 37964       3       com.ibm.icu.text.MessageFormat::format (1046 bytes)
Event: 2792.926 Thread 0x000000005665a800 nmethod 37964 0x0000000008708090 code [0x0000000008708d40, 0x0000000008713088]
Event: 2792.926 Thread 0x000000005665a800 37965       3       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.JavaCorrectionProcessor::hasCorrections (67 bytes)
Event: 2792.926 Thread 0x000000005665a800 nmethod 37965 0x00000000053a7650 code [0x00000000053a7820, 0x00000000053a8168]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 2776.940 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=285 (full 58):
 PSYoungGen      total 269824K, used 269745K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fd100000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 252416K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fa180000,0x00000000fa180000)
  from space 17408K, 99% used [0x00000000fb680000,0x00000000fc76c730,0x00000000fc780000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x00000000fa180000,0x00000000fa180000,0x00000000fb680000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 209211K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 47% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000ccc4ed58,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 146402K, capacity 157864K, committed 158164K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16639K, capacity 20363K, committed 20480K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2776.952 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=285 (full 58):
 PSYoungGen      total 273920K, used 16683K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fe180000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 252416K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fa180000)
  from space 21504K, 77% used [0x00000000fa180000,0x00000000fb1cac38,0x00000000fb680000)
  to   space 24064K, 0% used [0x00000000fca00000,0x00000000fca00000,0x00000000fe180000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 209219K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 47% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000ccc50d58,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 146402K, capacity 157864K, committed 158164K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16639K, capacity 20363K, committed 20480K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2777.619 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=286 (full 58):
 PSYoungGen      total 273920K, used 269099K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000fe180000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 252416K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fa180000,0x00000000fa180000)
  from space 21504K, 77% used [0x00000000fa180000,0x00000000fb1cac38,0x00000000fb680000)
  to   space 24064K, 0% used [0x00000000fca00000,0x00000000fca00000,0x00000000fe180000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 209219K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 47% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000ccc50d58,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 146415K, capacity 157864K, committed 158164K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16640K, capacity 20363K, committed 20480K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2777.638 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=286 (full 58):
 PSYoungGen      total 285184K, used 24060K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ff600000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 261120K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000faa00000)
  from space 24064K, 99% used [0x00000000fca00000,0x00000000fe17f2c8,0x00000000fe180000)
  to   space 32768K, 0% used [0x00000000faa00000,0x00000000faa00000,0x00000000fca00000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 219572K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 49% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd66d160,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 146415K, capacity 157864K, committed 158164K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16640K, capacity 20363K, committed 20480K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2778.135 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=287 (full 58):
 PSYoungGen      total 285184K, used 285180K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ff600000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 261120K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000faa00000,0x00000000faa00000)
  from space 24064K, 99% used [0x00000000fca00000,0x00000000fe17f2c8,0x00000000fe180000)
  to   space 32768K, 0% used [0x00000000faa00000,0x00000000faa00000,0x00000000fca00000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 219572K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 49% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cd66d160,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 146459K, capacity 157928K, committed 158164K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16643K, capacity 20363K, committed 20480K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2778.165 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=287 (full 58):
 PSYoungGen      total 293888K, used 32765K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 261120K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000faa00000)
  from space 32768K, 99% used [0x00000000faa00000,0x00000000fc9ff7a8,0x00000000fca00000)
  to   space 44544K, 0% used [0x00000000fd480000,0x00000000fd480000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 233937K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 52% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000ce4744a0,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 146459K, capacity 157928K, committed 158164K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16643K, capacity 20363K, committed 20480K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2778.603 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=288 (full 58):
 PSYoungGen      total 293888K, used 83665K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 261120K, 19% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000edcb4e90,0x00000000faa00000)
  from space 32768K, 99% used [0x00000000faa00000,0x00000000fc9ff7a8,0x00000000fca00000)
  to   space 44544K, 0% used [0x00000000fd480000,0x00000000fd480000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 233937K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 52% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000ce4744a0,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 146637K, capacity 158056K, committed 158420K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16662K, capacity 20363K, committed 20480K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2778.624 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=288 (full 58):
 PSYoungGen      total 300544K, used 26194K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 256000K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fa500000)
  from space 44544K, 58% used [0x00000000fd480000,0x00000000fee14b30,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 46592K, 0% used [0x00000000fa500000,0x00000000fa500000,0x00000000fd280000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 233937K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 52% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000ce4744a0,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 146637K, capacity 158056K, committed 158420K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16662K, capacity 20363K, committed 20480K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2778.624 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=289 (full 59):
 PSYoungGen      total 300544K, used 26194K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 256000K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fa500000)
  from space 44544K, 58% used [0x00000000fd480000,0x00000000fee14b30,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 46592K, 0% used [0x00000000fa500000,0x00000000fa500000,0x00000000fd280000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 233937K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 52% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000ce4744a0,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 146637K, capacity 158056K, committed 158420K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16662K, capacity 20363K, committed 20480K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2779.605 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=289 (full 59):
 PSYoungGen      total 300544K, used 0K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 256000K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fa500000)
  from space 44544K, 0% used [0x00000000fd480000,0x00000000fd480000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 46592K, 0% used [0x00000000fa500000,0x00000000fa500000,0x00000000fd280000)
 ParOldGen       total 443392K, used 228000K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000db100000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 443392K, 51% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cdea8078,0x00000000db100000)
 Metaspace       used 146637K, capacity 158056K, committed 158420K, reserved 1187840K
  class space    used 16662K, capacity 20363K, committed 20480K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 2792.911 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000959f058 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.getNextToken0()I @ 93
Event: 2792.912 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000959f058 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.getNextToken0()I @ 93
Event: 2792.912 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x000000000983a9d0 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(Ljava/lang/Object;ZLorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 70
Event: 2792.912 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000959f058 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.getNextToken0()I @ 93
Event: 2792.913 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000959f058 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.getNextToken0()I @ 93
Event: 2792.913 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x000000000983a9d0 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(Ljava/lang/Object;ZLorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 70
Event: 2792.913 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000959f058 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.getNextToken0()I @ 93
Event: 2792.914 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000959f058 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.getNextToken0()I @ 93
Event: 2792.914 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x000000000983a9d0 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(Ljava/lang/Object;ZLorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 70
Event: 2792.914 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000959f058 method=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.getNextToken0()I @ 93

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 2792.911 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 9> (0x00000000f0edede8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 2792.911 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 9> (0x00000000f0edf318) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 2792.911 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 11> (0x00000000f0edfc48) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 2792.911 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 11> (0x00000000f0ee02f8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 2792.912 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 11> (0x00000000f0ef64b0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 2792.912 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 908> (0x00000000f0f063e8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 2792.913 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 10841> (0x00000000f0f32bd8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 2792.913 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 261> (0x00000000f0f3fda8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 2792.914 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 36760> (0x00000000f0f781b8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 2792.914 Thread 0x000000005e160000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 814> (0x00000000f0f98108) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]

Events (10 events):
Event: 2792.920 Thread 0x000000000228f000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003de71b4 sp=0x000000000254cc20
Event: 2792.920 Thread 0x000000000228f000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000286787f sp=0x000000000254c9c8 mode 1
Event: 2792.920 Thread 0x000000000228f000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000006773b44 sp=0x000000000254cd00
Event: 2792.920 Thread 0x000000000228f000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000286787f sp=0x000000000254c9b8 mode 1
Event: 2792.920 Thread 0x000000000228f000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000007133274 sp=0x000000000254cda0
Event: 2792.920 Thread 0x000000000228f000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000286787f sp=0x000000000254cb68 mode 1
Event: 2792.920 Thread 0x000000000228f000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003de71b4 sp=0x000000000254cc90
Event: 2792.920 Thread 0x000000000228f000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000286787f sp=0x000000000254ca38 mode 1
Event: 2792.920 Thread 0x000000000228f000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000006773b44 sp=0x000000000254cd70
Event: 2792.920 Thread 0x000000000228f000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000286787f sp=0x000000000254ca38 mode 1
```

The log didn't fit into this message so the full version can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=au8B7HJu

Comment: You should open a bug report at oracle http://bugreport.java.com/

Comment: @Jens Should i use the subcategory "javac compiler / generics" for the bug report? I assume that because the exception occurs in "C2 CompilerThread1" but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Yes if it is wrong oracle will change it i think.

Answer (score 0):

Joining the club. `JDK 8u60` `WLS 12.1.3` (multithreaded test - REST Web service)
The more I use Java 8, the more I feel it is unstable and [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038895/java-8-performance-vs-java-7/33047398#33047398).
I guess Java 8 isn't mature for any PROD application (yet).

[image]